# Python, Tkinter, Checkbutton: Is there a way to check on/off value

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, checkbox

what i am trying to do is setup if statements to check if a checkbuttons value is on or off

what i was thinking was something like this

```
from Tkinter import *

def checkbutton_value():
    #If statement here
    #is their something like 

    #if checkbox_1.onvalue == True:
    #   checkbox_2.deselect()

    #if checkbox_1.varible == checkbox_1.onvalue:
    #   checkbox_2.deselect()

    print 'Need Help on lines 7-8 or 10-11'

root=Tk()

checkbox_1 = Checkbutton(root, text='1   ', command=checkbutton_value).pack()
checkbox_2 = Checkbutton(root, text='2   ', command=checkbutton_value).pack()

checkbox_3 = Checkbutton(root, text='QUIT', command=quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, **do not create and pack a widget on one line**.  `pack` returns `None`, so in your code above, `checkbox_1` is `None`.  Instead:

```
checkbox_1 = Checkbutton(root, text='1   ', command=checkbutton_value)
checkbox_1.pack()
```

Now, to get the value of the checkbutton:

```
def checkbutton_value1():
    if(var1.get()):
       var2.set(0)

def checkbutton_value2():
    if(var2.get()):
       var1.set(0)

var1=IntVar()
checkbox_1 = Checkbutton(root, text='1   ', variable=var1, command=checkbutton_value1)
checkbox_1.pack()
var2=IntVar()
checkbox_2 = Checkbutton(root, text='2   ', variable=var2, command=checkbutton_value2)
checkbox_2.pack()
```

It is often desireable to create your own checkbutton class for things like this:

```
class MyCheckButton(CheckButton):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.var=kwargs.get('variable',IntVar())
        kwargs['variable']=self.var
        Checkbutton.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def is_checked(self):
        return self.var.get()
```

Comment: Deleted my answer in lieu of your more detailed one. +1

Comment: Thanks i didnt no about the pack being None although i dont ever use pack/grid on the same line in real code but i guess there still is an effect in test code

Comment: @Crispy -- Also have a look at the `Radiobutton` widget ( http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm ).  That might be more suited for what you want then a series of checkbuttons.

Comment: Wow, wonderful. The `if` statement has to be called inside the function called by command.